# Eliminated out at this cut off

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Can we write: " Something is already eliminated out at this cut-off."

Comment: I get the vibe this site (http://ell.stackexchange.com/) would help you more than the site you are on right now.

Comment: I think it's General Reference that *"to eliminate **out**"* is not an established "phrasal verb".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's General Reference for people that speak the language with adequate fluency (eg, native speakers). I think the OP is not one of those people...

Comment: @Soylent Green: Exactly. Off Topic here, On Topic on ELL.

Answer (score 3):

I would rephrase this as

```
Something is already eliminated at this cut-off.
```

or

```
Something is already taken out at this cut-off.
```

or

```
Something has already been removed at this cut-off.
```